# Sanitize/Replace all Japanese, Chinese Korean, Russian etc. characters

Tags: php, regex

I have function that sanitizes URLs and filenames and it works fine with characters like `éáßöäü` as it replaces them with `eassoau` etc. using `str_replace($a, $b, $value)`. But how can I replace all characters from Chinese, Japanese … languages? And if replacing is not possible because it's not easy to determine, how can I remove all those characters? Of course I could first sanitize it like above and then remove all "non-latin" characters. But maybe there is another good solution to that?

**Edit/addition**

As asked in the comments: What is the purpose of my question? We had a client that had content in English, German and Russian language at first. Later on there came some chinese pages. Two problems occurred with the URLs:

- the first sanitizer killed all 'non-ascii-characters' and possibly returned 'blank' (invalid) clean-URLs
- the client experienced that in some Browser clean URLs with Chinese characters wouldn't work

The first point led me to the shot to replace those characters, which is of course, as stated in the question and the comments confirmed it, not possible. Maybe now somebody is answering that in all modern browsers (starting with IE8) this ain't an issue anymore. I would also be glad to hear about that too.

Comment: If you want to be sure just whitelist the allowed characters?

Comment: You are partially acknowledging yourself that replacing might not be possible, but as you explicitly mention it with respect to Chinese or Japanese: What would you expect those to be replaced with? As opposed to `éáßöäü`, there is no general well-defined convention for replacing Chinese or Japanese characters with ASCII characters.

Comment: Can you restate your problem? What is this supposed to be good for?

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. I've updated my answer. Hopefully it gives a better idea what I wanted to ask. And thanks for confirming my thoughts on the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for Japanese, as an example, there is usually a *romanji* representation of everything which uses only ascii characters and still gives a reversable and understandable representation of the original characters. However translating something into romanji requires that you know the correct pronounciation, and that usually depends on the meaning or the context in which the characters are used. That makes it hard if not impossible to simply convert everything correcly (or at least not efficiently doable for a simple sanitizer).

The same applies to Chinese, in an even worse way. Korean on the other hand has a very simple character set which should be easily translateable into a roman representation. Another common problem though is that there is not a *single* romanization method; those languages usually have different ones which are used by different people (Japanese for example has two common romanizations).

So it really depends on the actual language you are working with; while you might be able to make it work for *some* languages another problem would be to detect which language you are actually working with (e.g. Japanese and Chinese share a lot of characters but meanings, pronounciations and as such romanizations are usually incompatible). Especially for simple *santization* of file names, I don’t think it is worth to invest such an amount of work and processing time into it.

Maybe you should work in a different direction: Make your file names simply work as unicode filenames. There are actually a very few number of characters that are truly invalid in file systems (`*|\/:"<>?`) so it would be way easier to simply filter those out and otherwise support unicode file names.

Comment: Many thanks for confirming what I already thought and this well-written answer. I think I will go with UTF8 encoding on the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

You could run it through your existing sanitizer, then anything not latin, you could convert to [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

Comment: I don't see why not. I assume he needs to remove unicode, and restrict to ascii characters. Punycode is a reversible method, so the original filename can be put back as and when required on the server or the client in a scriptable way.

Comment: Always i think, punycode uses for domain names only, but noone disalow to use it for filenames. But this is not, what question author wants.

Comment: Thanks for your answer – sounds interesting on the URLs. I think I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Being reversable, means you could store the url in punycode, then if people search using unicode, you can convert their search too, and match it to your punycode url.

Answer (score 1):

So, as i understand you need some character relation tables for every language, and replace characters by relation in this table.
By example, for translit russian symbols to latin synonyms, we use this tables =) Or classes, which use this tables =)
It's intresting, i finded it right now http://derickrethans.nl/projects.html#translit

Comment: Thanks for you link to translit. This seems very powerful, but unfortunately we don't have the possibility to install extensions. In the first part you said something about a conversion table. Somehow the link is missing or did you mean the tables that translit uses?

Comment: @insertusernamehere, here example of such class http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2650-PHP-Transliterate-cyrillic-text-using-latin-characters.html
It's old, but we intrested for principle of this. If you will have tables with all non-latin symbols, you can change them.